How to capture HTTP response status codes with Micrometer and Prometheus in a Java/Spark application?
I'm working on a Java project using Spark, Micrometer, and Prometheus for monitoring. I've successfully implemented metrics for endpoint call counts and response times. However, I'm struggling to capture the HTTP response status codes (200, 400, 500, etc.).
I've tried using Counters with tags to store the status code as a value, but I haven't been able to get Micrometer to register them. Here's my relevant code snippet (other counters and endpoints omitted for brevity):
public class MiAplicacion {

  static PrometheusMeterRegistry registry = new PrometheusMeterRegistry(PrometheusConfig.DEFAULT);

  static Counter peticionesPorEstadoCounter = Counter.builder("http.requests")
      .tag("method", "GET")
      .tag("path", "/tipoRespuesta")
      .register(registry);

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Spark.port(8080);
    Spark.get("/metrics", (req, res) -> registry.scrape());
    Spark.get("/tipoRespuesta", (req, res) -> {
      int estadoRespuesta = tipoRespuesta();
      res.status(estadoRespuesta);
      peticionesPorEstadoCounter.increment(); // Track counter here
      return res;
    });
  }

  public static int tipoRespuesta() {
    Random random = new Random();
    int randomNumber = random.nextInt(3) + 1;
    int estadoRespuesta;
    switch (randomNumber) {
      case 1:
        estadoRespuesta = 200;
        break;
      case 2:
        estadoRespuesta = 400;
        break;
      default:
        estadoRespuesta = 500;
    }
    return estadoRespuesta;
  }
}

Here's my project's POM for reference:
<dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>io.micrometer</groupId>
    <artifactId>micrometer-core</artifactId>
    <version>1.8.0</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>io.micrometer</groupId>
    <artifactId>micrometer-registry-prometheus</artifactId>
    <version>1.8.0</version>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
    <groupId>com.sparkjava</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.9.3</version>
  </dependency>
</dependencies>

Any suggestions on how to effectively capture HTTP response status codes and register them as metrics in this scenario?
